# Vee-validate - [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: validate

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vee-validate, vue-directives

I want to validate text fields, trying below code :

```
 <input v-validate="result.val=='Required' ? 'required' : ''" v-model="required" :name="f_name" type="text"/>
```

but getting this error:

> app.js:48089 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: validate

Trying this:

```
<ValidationProvider name="phone" :rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
  <input class="form-control" :name="phone" type="text" v-model="form.phone"/>
  </ValidationProvider>
```

Comment: are you using vee-validate? if yes please provide its version

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim: Version of vee-validate  "vee-validate": "^3.3.9",

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [migration guide](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/migration.html#removed-v-validate-directive) this directive is removed in v3.x :

> Fields that had the `v-validate` directive needs to be wrapped by `ValidationProvider` component now, and they need to use v-model to properly tag themselves for vee-validate.
> So this:

```
<input type="text" name="field" v-validate="'required'">
<span>{{ errors.first('field') }}</span>
```

Will be re-written as this:

```
<ValidationProvider name="field" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
  <input type="text" v-model="value">
  <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
</ValidationProvider>
```

Your code should be like :

```
<ValidationProvider name="f_name" :rules="result.val=='Required' ? 'required' : ''" v-slot="{ errors }">
<input v-model="required" :name="f_name" type="text"/>
</ValidationProvider>
```

You should add this to `main.js` :

```
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';

Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
```

If you are not using a bundler and using vee-validate in the browser or from a CDN:

```
<script>
  // ...
  Vue.component('validation-provider', VeeValidate.ValidationProvider);
  // ...
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, now i'm getting this error : Unknown custom element: <ValidationProvider> - did you register the component correctly

Comment: I'm getting this error : Property or method "field" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: replace `name="field"` by `name="f_name"`

Comment: i'm getting error : Property or method "required" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render and in the error  part v-slot="{ errors }"

Comment: I have added my code snippet in my question what i'm trying just now

Comment: replace `:rules="required" ` by `:rules="result.val=='Required' ? 'required' : ''"`

Comment: for now i have made it simple by removing the condition to test it but it is still not working,later on i can add that condition of required,if this simple validation works,

Comment: could you make a running code example in codesandbox in order to debug it

Comment: Ok Thanks i will post it.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-dubinsky-wy573?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue i have tried this, It is working with Validation observer can i make it simple form, Can you please check it.

Comment: how did you fix the issue?

Comment: The issue i think was i was using  <form></form> tag in place of Validation observer

Comment: it looks that the observer takes the form as tag value and then it renders it